# Laravel - add fields to table

Tags: php, laravel

I use Laravel 5.6, I come from Symfony development and Doctrine ORM.

What is the way to add fields to a table ? I want to add some fields to the user table. So I created a migration :

```
php artisan make:migration add_data_users --table=users
```

And I added the fields in the migration. But when I try to migrate, I got this error :

> Base table or view already exists: 1050 Table 'permissions' already exists

This table was already migrated, but it seems that migration rebuild all schemas (?!). In Symfony, I only add fields to the Entity, here, do I have to create a migration ? and then, how to apply only the new migration ? I tried to add the name of the migration to the command, but it doesn't work.

***Edit***

It seemed that I had 2 migrations concerning the *permissions* table, just look at your migrations carefuly, I deleted the second migration file, and it worked.

Comment: `php artisan make:migration add_data_users` and put in up method this code `     Schema::table('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->string('data')->after('password');
        });`

Comment: You have some migration problems. How is your `migrations` table? It looks like it tries to run again migration on `permissions` table while it still exists. It has nothing to do with your added new migration file. And the command looks good ;)

Comment: In my migration table, I have the migration concerning the permissions table (2018_06_09_213829_create_permission_tables). This table was already migrated, since the table is created, and I have it in my migration table (with batch = 1)

Comment: @VincentDecaux Are you in a development environment or a production environment?

Comment: In development environnement.

Comment: Edit : ok, it seems that I had 2 migrations for the permissions table, I really don't know why since it comes from an external vendor.

Comment: @VincentDecaux Maybe you published the files of that package twice. Luckily you figured it out! You can write an answer yourself and accept that if you want for future reference and as help for other users!

Comment: True, weird, thanks for the answers all.

Answer (score -2):

You should create new migration like:

```
php artisan make:migration update_users_table
```

**UpdateUsersTable.php** //your new migration

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class UpdateUsersTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::table('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->string('name', 36)->nullable()->default(null);
        });
    }
```

**Note**: Please run migration for specific table

After create test folder in migrations folder then newly created migration moved/copied in test folder and run below command in your terminal/cmd like:

```
php artisan migrate --path=database/migrations/test/
```

Comment: This is what I've done, but I can't migrate only the last migration created ?

Comment: If you read the question this is clearly not the problem. The migration is in correct, but there is another migration that is throwing an error. Also note that dropping a table in the down method is very bad, because in the up method you just added a column. The down method should remove just that column, not the whole table.

Comment: @VincentDecaux: Please try run migration for specific table so please check my Note in my answer

Comment: @AddWebSolutionPvtLtd If you run `php artisan migrate` but there is a problem, that indicates that somewhere in your workflow you made an error. Running a single migration is a bypass and doesn't solve the issue. It just creates a workflow which is more difficult. Fix the error instead of bypassing it.

Comment: I agree @DouwedeHaan, I think I only have to run `php artisan migrate` since my other tables are already migrated. I just don't understand why it tries to run previous migrations.

Comment: I can not see other migration files, but maybe `permissions` table is altered in other migration files?